# Pass a value and call previous, current and next values in order

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using PDO. I want to be able to fetch 3 values from 3 different rows using a single query. I've got a table as below.

```
itemID    |  Item_Name
____________________
125       |  apple
297       |  Lychee
851       |  Mango
005       |  Orange
1009      |  Strawberry
```

I want to be able to send an `Item_Name` and sort the table by `Item_Name` and to be able to call the next `Item_Name` and the previous `Item_Name`. How can I do this?

e.g.:

1. if the `$passedItem` is `Orange` I want to output `Mango` and `Orange` and `Strawberry`.
2. if the `$passedItem` is `Mango` I want to output `Lychee` and `Mango` and `Orange`

Using the `on()` operator did not work because only one Item_Name could be passed on to the query.

```
$sql = "SELECT Item_Name FROM itemsTable WHERE Item_Name = :passedItem" ORDER BY ASC;
$stmt = $con_db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(':passedItem'=>"Orange"));
$rslt = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: @Barmar I googled for hours but I did not come across that.

Comment: Maybe just get all items, fetch until you find your item, then display index -1 and index +1 ... this is a hard question since your table ID's are useless in your case... If your table is huge, that "whole fetching" solution will not be very effective...

Comment: @Barmar next + previous in case of id ordered rows, i'm ok with you. But his specific case with non ordered id's is different...

Comment: @Julo0sS It doesn't matter what you order by, the technique is the same. He says he wants to `ORDER BY Item_Name`.

Comment: @Julo0sS - you're absolutely correct

Comment: Just use the same column in the `WHERE` clause as the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: @Barmar the solution might be easy from your standards but I find it very confusing. Could you please show it in a simplified way?

Comment: Just take the answers in that question, replace `id` with `item_name` and remove the `private IS NULL` test.

Comment: @Barmar how can I output the results? `$rslt[0]["item_name"];` does not work. Could you help on that?

Comment: I've posted an answer. I stupidly assumed you knew how to take a MySQL query and put it into PDO syntax.

Comment: It's case sensitive, so it should be `$rslt[0]["Item_Name"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is based on [MySQL: Conditionally selecting next and previous rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169233/mysql-conditionally-selecting-next-and-previous-rows?lq=1).

```
$sql = "(SELECT Item_Name FROM itemsTable
         WHERE Item_Name < ?
         ORDER BY Item_Name DESC
         LIMIT 1)
        UNION ALL
        (SELECT Item_Name FROM itemsTable
         WHERE ItemName = ?)
        UNION ALL
        (SELECT Item_Name FROM itemsTable
         WHERE ItemName > ?
         ORDER BY Item_Name ASC
         LIMIT 1)";
$stmt = $con_db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array("Orange", "Orange", "Orange"));
$rslt = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

You need to pass `Orange` three times to fill in all the placeholders.

You can then output it with:

```
foreach($rslt as $row) {
    echo $row['Item_Name'] . '<br>';
}
```